# htaccess 301 redirect everything except /admin

Tags: redirection, users, .htaccess

I have been scratching my head for almost half an hour already because of this. I don't know what I am doing wrong, might just be under my nose, but i just cant see it. Here's what I have on my .htaccess

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I access example.com/admin, i am still redirected to newsite.com/admin.
Can anyone please advise? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on `RewriteBase /`.
I checked your code with this [online tool](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it was working fine.
Toggling comment for rewritebase line will help but other rules might get affected. Instead, modify your condition and remove the slash. It should work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(?!admin)  http://www.newsite.com
```